# How to show which method pointer a variable points to?

Tags: delphi

I have decalred

```
type  TProcedure = procedure(const messageText : String) of object;
```

and later have a variable of that type `decodeProcedure : TProcedure;`   which gets assigned in various places.

When I am stopped on a breakpint, how can I see which procedure the variablle is pointing to?

If I `Debug/evaluate` or `add watch` I get an error `E2035 Not enough actual parameters`

(Delphi XE 2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can evaluate the address of the decodeProcedure method using the @ operator and adding that expression to the watch list windows, to see to which procedure points you can use the `local variables` window.

try this code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TProcedure = procedure(const messageText : String) of object;
  TFooClass = class
     decodeProcedure  : TProcedure;
   public
     procedure Bar(const messageText : String);
     procedure DoIt;
  end;

Var
  F : TFooClass;
{ TFooClass }

procedure TFooClass.Bar(const messageText: String);
begin
  Writeln(messageText);
end;

procedure TFooClass.DoIt;
begin
  if Assigned(decodeProcedure) then //put a break point here
   decodeProcedure('Hello');
end;

begin
  try
     F:=TFooClass.Create;
     try
       F.decodeProcedure:=F.Bar;
       F.DoIt;
     finally
      F.Free;
     end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

And this a sample IDE screenshoot

[image]

As you see the `local variables` window shows which the decodeprocedure points to the `TFooClass.Bar` method.

**UPDATE**
 You can also add the `Self` expression to the watch list to get the same results

[image]

Comment: +1 and the answer. Thanks for such a quick and informative response!!

Comment: hmm, when I View/Debug Windows ... I do not have an option for "Local Variables" ... perhaps vecause I have only XE2 starter?

Comment: I just check the [feature matrix of delphi xe2](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/images/41563/Delphi_XE2_Feature_Matrix.pdf) and the `Expandable local variables view` is not available in the starter edition :(